# Why do I get an Error 500 when loading all news items?

Tags: 7, ajax, views, paging

I developed a News Website.

I have more than 5000+ news items on the site, displayed in a view with a pager (100 items per page).

In my view configuration, I enabled *Expose items per page* and *Include all items*.

[image]

When I select the -ALL- link, the site displays an AJAX error 500, meaning I cannot display all news items.

Can this be fixed, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

The error 500 is most likely caused by Drupal running out of available resources when trying to retried all the results it's being asked to serve. You may wish to consider the following:

- Use a caching mechanism to allow the results to be served without using all available memory or running out of time.
- Increase the memory available to Drupal/PHP.
- Make changes to your view to reduce the memory requirement (fewer items shown per page etc.)

With that said I fail to see the usefulness of a page containing 1000 news stories and you may wish to re-evaluate having the -All- option and/or the option to have 1000 items per page.